# Trouble adding LXD Clusters to MAAS

Tags: ubuntu, lxd, maas

## Trouble with Setting Up LXD Clusters in MAAS

Hello! I have been working with maas to try and setup a LXD cluster.

### Setup

- Maas Controller:
  Dell Optiplex (nothing special, just an extra computer that I had around.)
  The MAAS controller is setup as the DHCP server for the network. I just have one fabric with a 10.113.1.0/24 subnet for no particular reason. Setup is mainly proof-of-concept for now.
- MAAS clients:
  3x Dell PowerEdge T630's with Intel 10GB network cards and IPMI.

### Versions

- Maas Controller:

```
$ snap list | grep maas
maas                       3.2.0~beta6-11974-g.58f181df4  21449  3.2/beta         canonical**  -
maas-cli                   0.6.5                          13     latest/stable    canonical**  -
maas-test-db               12.4-22-g.aed1dfe              91     3.1/stable       canonical**  -
```

(This was also tested with 3.1/stable with the same results.)

- The Dell PowerEdge servers are deployed with MAAS with the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS cloud image.

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ snap list | grep lxd
lxd     5.2-79c3c3b  23155  latest/stable  canonical**  -
```

### What I have tried

I have tried following the following articles:

- https://maas.io/docs/whats-new-in-maas#heading--lxd-clusters
- https://maas.io/docs/how-to-use-lxd

I am able to get the LXD cluster going using `lxd init` on the first Dell PowerEdge server and following the prompts. I then add the other two PowerEdge's using `lxd init` again and copy/pasting their join tokens. However, when I add the LXD host from the maas KVM page, it just shows up as a single cluster.

### Related Info

MAAS Dashboard:

```
$ maas admin machines read | jq 'insert jq magic here'
HOSTNAME      SYSID   POWER    STATUS    OWNER  TAGS             POOL     VLAN      FABRIC    SUBNET
--------      -----   -----    ------    -----  ----             ----     ----      ------    ------
fun-shad      ncw7a4  on       Deployed  ben    metal            default  untagged  fabric-1  
moral-dassie  krrkfk  on       Deployed  ben    metal            default  untagged  fabric-1  
new-drum      p68mcg  on       Deployed  ben    metal            default  untagged  fabric-1
```

LXD Cluster:

```
root@fun-shad:~# lxc cluster list
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+
|     NAME     |           URL            |      ROLES      | ARCHITECTURE | FAILURE DOMAIN | DESCRIPTION | STATE  |      MESSAGE      |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+
| fun-shad     | https://10.113.1.73:8443 | database-leader | x86_64       | default        |             | ONLINE | Fully operational |
|              |                          | database        |              |                |             |        |                   |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+
| moral-dassie | https://10.113.1.74:8443 | database        | x86_64       | default        |             | ONLINE | Fully operational |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+
| new-drum     | https://10.113.1.72:8443 | database        | x86_64       | default        |             | ONLINE | Fully operational |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Images:

- [Adding LXD Host from KVM Dashboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPca1.png)
- [Copying LXD trust.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QPRV.png)
- [Pasting LXD trust to LXD leader.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMZkQ.png)
- [Confirming that the trust was added successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGZ5e.png)
- [MAAS only shows that the LXD cluster is a single host.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn9Eh.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps!

Comment: Also, the certificate posted in the images will not be used in production and has already been deleted for anyone curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved: RTFD

Turns out I shouldn’t have ignored the fact that only Ubuntu 20 LTS is currently supported. I redeployed with Ubuntu 20.04 instead of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Hopefully support is added for Ubuntu 22 soon.